# why clientWidth is 0 in IE

Tags: html, angular, internet-explorer

I have a Angular 4 component where template has only a canvas (no CSS template)

```
<canvas #mychart>
</canvas>
```

I use this component inside another component where we adjust the width using flex.

```
<myComp #myMini class="cssforflex" [style.width.px]="Width"></mycomp>
```

In order to adjust the width when whole component resize (say on window resize), we are relying on `elementRef.nativeElement.clientWidth` property of `myComp`.

So, for every resize event we check for the `clientWidth` and apply that to width of canvas.

This works perfectly fine in Chrome but in IE the `clientWidth` is always coming as 0. Any idea why?

Comment: Thank you Kaiido for looking into it. I put that tag because it was relevant to my problem. Giving another thought, I dont think it is really needed because the whole problem is with not getting width of component. So, I will remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I put style `display: inline-block` in component.

I still am not sure why it worked. So, if anyone know, please do let me know.